# MVC 3 WCF Rest Service In Partial Trust

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf-web-api

I have created a MVC 3 WCF Rest project using the tutorial described [here](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20started%3a%20Building%20a%20simple%20web%20api). The only problem is that am able to run the project and access the rest api when the application is running at high trust level but when i change the trust level to medium i get the following when i access the service

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationPermission, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +31
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.CheckAccess(IConfigurationContextProviderInternal element) +12116253
   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupServiceBehaviors(String behaviorName, ContextInformation context) +12238226
   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement, Action`1 addBaseAddress) +137
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.LoadConfigurationSectionInternal(ConfigLoader configLoader, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceSection) +67
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.ApplyConfiguration() +108
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +192
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Type serviceType, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +49
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +151
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Http.HttpServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +63
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Http.Activation.HttpConfigurableServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, IHttpHostConfigurationBuilder builder, Uri[] baseAddresses) +40
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Http.Activation.HttpConfigurableServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +79
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +420
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +1440
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +44
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath) +615
```

Please Help.. any ideas on how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Web API project currently doesn't work in partial trust. PT support is planned, but it hasn't been implemented yet.